# appending results of a loop to a new column error in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames `dat1` and `dat2` like this:

```
head(dat1, 2)
# X     x                 sample    chromosome     a_b  coverage
# 1     91.4245014245     A1        1              a    NA
# 22    91.4245014245     A2        1              b    NA

head(dat2, 2)
# sample_id     coverage
# A1            8.439
# A2            0.673
```

**Question:** I would like to cycle through each `sample` in `dat1`. Then see if it matches to any `sample_id` in `dat2` and then append the corresponding `coverage`-value from `dat2` to the `coverage`-value in `dat1`.

**What I've tried**: This is what I've tried so far:

```
dat1 = read.csv("y_v_coverage.csv", header=T)
dat1$coverage = NA
dat1 = as.data.frame(dat1)

dat2 = read.csv("samples_x_coverage.csv", header=T)
dat2 = as.data.frame(dat2)

for (i in dat1$sample) {
    for (j in dat2$sample_id) {
        if (i == j) {
            dat1$coverage[i] = dat2$coverage[j]
        }
    }
}
```

But it keeps giving me the following error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "coverage", value = c(NA_integer_,  : 
>         replacement has 5924 rows, data has 5923

This error seems to have many different meanings and I can't seem to figure out how it is related to what I have done. Usually, it seems as though this error comes up if you don't create a column full of NA, but I've done that.

Comment: You could try `merge()`. Something like `merge(dat1, dat2, by.x="sample", by.y="sample_id", all.y=TRUE)` should work, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge would be better option for this. You can simply apply the merge function lije this:

> merge(df1,df2,by.x ="sample", by.y= "sample1",all.x =TRUE)

So by this we are defining that all the observations of df1 should be there if anything is not found, that should not be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually trying to merge `dat1` and `dat2` based on the value for `sample` and `sample_id`.

You can merge two data frames using `merge()`. In your case, you will have to specify which columns in `dat1` and `dat2` you are trying to merge on, because the columns don't carry the same name. This is done by the `by.x` and `by.y` arguments:

```
merge(dat1, dat2, by.x="sample", by.y="sample_id", all.x=TRUE)
#      sample  X    x          chromosome a_b  coverage.x coverage.y
# 1     A1     1    91.4245    1          a    NA         8.439
# 2     A2     22   91.4245    1          b    NA         0.673
```

Note that you can just drop the `coverage` column you created for `dat1` and you'll end up with exactly what you're looking for:

```
#      sample  X    x         chromosome a_b   coverage
# 1     A1     1    91.4245   1          a     8.439
# 2     A2     22   91.4245   1          b     0.673
```